# How does a generic in typescript work if it has extend in it

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at

```
type ComponentProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>> =
    T extends JSXElementConstructor<infer P>
        ? P
        : T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
            ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
            : {};
```

and I'm confused by how `T` can extend something else. When `T` is used in the body of the type, is it extended already? Would really appreciate it if someone can break down line by line how this works.

Comment: The same piece of code you wrote is actually explained near the end of this article https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/

Comment: _"and I'm confused by how `T` can extend something else"_ It's not, you're checking to see if `T` extends something more specific. For example if `T` is constrained to `'a' | 'b'`, it may be useful to check if `T` is `'a'` or `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

When used in a declaration of a generic type, it is a *constraint*.

So:

```
type WithName<T extends { id: number }> = T & { name: string }

type A = WithName<{ id: number, age: number }>
// { id: number, age: number, name: string }

type B = WithName<{ age: number }>
// type error because T is not assignable to the constraint
```

`T` must be a subtype of the constraint. That is `T` must be assignable to that constraint. It may be more specific than that, but it *may not* be less specific.

---

However, this:

```
type IsString<T> = T extends string ? string : never
type A = IsString<string> // string
type B = IsString<number> // never
```

Is a conditional type. Here `extends` operates similar-ish to `===` in a ternary. If whatever `T` is `extends` (is a subtype of, or is assignable to) what comes after it, then resolve the positive branches type, else resolve type negative branches type.

---

Lastly, this uses conditional types to infer a type.

```
type AwaitedPromise<T extends Promise<unknown>> =
  T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never

type A = AwaitedPromise<Promise<string>> // string
```

This type has a constraint of a `Promise` with an unknown resolved type. It then uses a conditional type to infer an inner piece of that type. Then that that inferred type is returned. In this case `T extends Promise<infer U>` is guaranteed to be truthy because of the constraint for `T`, but this syntax is *required* to use the `infer` keyword.

---

Putting all that together:

```
// Constrain T to be one of two things.
type ComponentProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>> =
    // If T is a react constructor, then infer it's props.
    T extends JSXElementConstructor<infer P>
        ?
            // T is a react constructor, return the props type
            P 
        :
            // T is not a react constructor, check if it is a `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`
            T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
                // Return a union of the types that are from the named keys.
                ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]

                // Return an empty object if neither of the two conditionals matched
                : {};
```